# Javascript - if the width of an element is 100%, do something

Tags: javascript, html, css

How do I force javascript to do the following?
If the width of an element with the id `myBar` is 100%, change the style of an element with the ID `result` to be "block" (it's set to `none`)?
Please answer!

Code: html

```
<div id="myProgress">
  <div id="myBar"></div>
</div>
<button onclick="move()">Run Malware Code Scan</button>
        <p id="result">
<em>Fount 142 threats!</em> Take responsibility please!
        </p>
```

Code: CSS

```
#myProgress {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #ebf442;
}
#myBar {
    width: 1%;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: #ed4949;
}

#result {display:none;}
ul li {list-style-type:square;}
```

Code: JS

```
<script>
function move() {
    var elem = document.getElementById("myBar"); 
    var width = 1;
    var id = setInterval(frame, 3);
    function frame() {
        if (width >= 100) {
            clearInterval(id);
        } else {
            width++; 
            elem.style.width = width + '%'; 
        }
    }
}
</script>
<script>
if (document.getElementById("myBar").style.width= "100%")
document.getElementById("result").style.display ="block"
</script>
```

**P.S.: I'm a beginner at JS!**

Comment: No code, no html, no help

Comment: It depends on what you're trying to see if it's 100% of the width of. Are you trying to see if it covers the whole width of the page? Or the whole width of another element?

Comment: @JaromandaX Are you happy now? I added the code that I used.

Comment: @HentccL It's not about being happy but about rules, we are here to help, not to do your homework. Have some more respect to people that wants to help you.

Answer (score 3):

## Edit

You can change display to `block` in your `frame` function when you check if width is `>= 100`. Wouldn't that solve your problem?

```
<script>
function move() {
    var elem = document.getElementById("myBar"); 
    var width = 1;
    var id = setInterval(frame, 3);
    function frame() {
        if (width >= 100) {
            clearInterval(id);
            document.getElementById("result").style.display = "block";
        } else {
            width++; 
            elem.style.width = width + '%'; 
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Sorry, but that will not work. It was obviously an error to use the assignment operator instead of the `==` operator but the code might be performed before the 100% width is reached by the interval calls. It would be better to set  display to "block" before the `clearInterval` in the if block. Then the with =100% condition ist fullfilled.  If you agree, would you correct/extend your answer?

Comment: @PeterPaulKiefer Done.

Answer (score 0):

**The problem of style properties**

The `element.style.property` returns no value until the css is applied from the tag i.e `<div style="..."></div>`.

So your code is not working. You should apply the width css from the tag to make your code work.

```
<div id="myProgress">
  <div id="myBar" style="width: 100%;"></div>
</div>
<button onclick="move()">Run Malware Code Scan</button>
<p id="result">
  <em>Fount 142 threats!</em> Take responsibility please!
</p>
```

As Oen44 figured out, there is a syntax error too in your if condition (== is written as =).